# How to compute equation with exponents?

Tags: sequences-and-series, roots

I want to find $a$, where that term satisfies this equation:

$$a + a(1-a) + a(1-a)^2 + \cdots + a(1-a)^{15} = 0.5$$

I could write that as a sum from 0 to 15, but still it is unclear to me how should I proceed, any ideas *please*?

Comment: Do you know how to sum a geometric series?

Comment: Hmm you mean that I should find a constant factor for that? I am not sure @David, it sure rings a bell, but from a quick Yahoo search I made, I couldn't find anything *really*helpful.

Comment: Take $a$ common then the constant factor is $(1-a)$

Comment: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/series5.htm

Comment: I just found that link @David too, I should find the ratio and will be easy.

Comment: That really means that you don't want to try.

Comment: @MayankDeora I deleted my comment because someone answered. No, that's not true! If I didn't want to, why going to search for what David advised me to? :)

Comment: Oh why a downvote? I mean how much better could the question be for someone with my knowledge?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a r^k = a \frac{1-r^n}{1-r}.$$

Substitute $n=16$ and $r=1-a$.

Comment: John thanks, if I am not mistaken this will yield $1 - (1 - a)^{16} = 0.5$, right? (damn, I don't think my question was so bad to have a negative score :/ )

Comment: Yep, then just solve for $a$.

Comment: Well, it will be $0.5 = (1 - a)^{16}$, then what John? I mean if it was squared, I would take the square root, but now what?

Comment: And if it was cubed, you'd take the cube root.  And if it was raised to the $16$th power ...

Comment: I have never used things like that, will search for them, thanks! :)

Comment: The next step would be $0.5^{1/16} = 1-a$.  Another way to write it would be $\sqrt[16]{0.5} = 1-a$.  It's read "the sixteenth root of $0.5$."